# Custom Post Type - Permalink errors

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I'm quite confident with WordPress and have used for a couple of years now but this one error has got me stumped.

Basically, I have a standard custom post type for a projects page, so it pulls through the info from the CPT then click on one and its goes through to the single.php of that CPT but, I have used this WordPress blank theme (regretting it) http://html5blank.com/ and it only works when there are no permalinks set, so just on the page ID, as soon as I switch it to pretty permalinks it error, even when you 'View Page' from the editor. I have tried resetting the .htaccess but no luck.

Please someone have a look at this - will create an Admin for you and will buy you a coffee for your time as I am pulling my hair out. I'm not sure whether to put the link on here or just direct message me for a link.

Thank you

edit*** This is the CPT I using

```
function projects_post_type()
{
    register_post_type('projects', // Register Custom Post Type
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Projects', 'testimonials'), // Rename these to suit
            'singular_name' => __('Project', 'testimonials'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'testimonials'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Project', 'testimonials'),
        'edit' => __('Edit', 'testimonials'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Project', 'testimonials'),
        'new_item' => __('New Project', 'testimonials'),
        'view' => __('View Project', 'testimonials'),
        'view_item' => __('View Project', 'testimonials'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Project', 'testimonials'),
        'not_found' => __('No Project Custom Posts found', 'testimonials'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Project Custom Posts found in Trash', 'testimonials')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
    'has_archive' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'thumbnail',
        'custom-fields',
        'page-attributes'
    ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
    'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
    'taxonomies' => array() // Add Category and Post Tags support
));
}

flush_rewrite_rules( false );
```

Comment: Are there any permalink plugins or CPT plugins active? Is it also possible to see the CPT code so we can examine it?

Comment: Yeah I will add the CPT to the original question :) no CPT or permalinks plugins active

Comment: I see nothing wrong, and it seems that you have copied/adjusted the HTML5Blank function.php file. Can you try the following: a) Remove the flush_rewrite_rules(false); line. b) deactivate the theme by switching to default WP theme. c) Change permalink structure to %post_title% d) re-activate the HTML5Blank theme with your code inside that functions.php file? (or the child theme you've created?)

Comment: Also: don't forget this line: add_action('init', 'projects_post_type'); // Add our HTML5 Blank Custom Post Type

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: No just working on it now - no luck

Comment: Would you be able to have a look at this for me directly - if I give you login details?

Comment: Look me up on FB, same username as here. Send me a message, I will be keeping an eye on my inbox